# Как выбрать максимальное значение в связанной таблице в yii2

Tags: php, sql, yii2, activerecord

Имеется две сущности: employee и department. Связь - many to many. У меня есть три таблицы: employee(id, name, salary), department(id, name) и department_employee(department_id, employee_id).

php код:

```
class Employee extends ActiveRecord
{
...
    public function getDepartments()
    {
        return $this
            ->hasMany(Department::className(), ['id' => 'department_id'])
            ->viaTable('departments_employees', ['employee_id' => 'id']);
    }
}

class Department extends ActiveRecord
{
...
    public function getEmployees()
    {
        return $this
            ->hasMany(Employee::className(), ['id' => 'employee_id'])
            ->viaTable('departments_employees', ['department_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

Задача: получить коллекцию с  Department со всеми его значениями +  максимальные значения salary из присоединенной таблицы.
P.S. salary is integer.

UPD: Нужно реализовать такой запрос

```
"SELECT department.name, MAX(employee.salary), COUNT(employee.id) FROM `department` 
INNER JOIN departments_employees
ON department.id = departments_employees.department_id
INNER JOIN employee
ON employee.id = departments_employees.employee_id
GROUP BY department.id;"
```

Comment: Выглядит как учебное задание, покажите ваши устремления к решению задачи, в чём именно возникла проблема реализации?

Comment: Данные из таблиц бд для рендеринга таблицы(верстка).
Таблица содержит колонки: Название отдела, кол-во сотрудников и максимальная  з/плата сотрудника. Получаю из бд таким образом Department::find(). Т.е.  элемент коллекции имеет в свойствах имя отдела и коллекцию Employment. Как грамотно вывести из бд максимальную заработную плату сотрудника для отдела?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Документация помогла. Вот так выглядит формирование запроса:

```
Department::find()
            ->select(['MAX(employee.salary) AS maxSalary', 'COUNT(employee.id) AS quantity','department.id','department.name'])
            ->innerJoin('departments_employees', 'departments_employees.department_id = department.id')
            ->innerJoin('employee','departments_employees.employee_id = employee.id')
            ->groupBy('department.id')
            ->asArray()
```